# JTextArea Does Not Display File Contents On New Lines

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea

I'm having an issue using a JTextArea within a scrollpane. I can read from a textfile, but the contents are all showing up on one line. I have tried various methods using append and trying to break the line, but with no success.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class SplashScreen extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    JButton mobile;
    JButton browser;
    JLabel welc;
    JPanel home;
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Jimbob\\Desktop\\DisWorkspace\\TrustWizard\\welcometwo.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    int lines = 10;

    public String read()
    {
        String savetext = "";

        try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String text = null;

            while((text = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                savetext += text;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException jim)
        {
            jim.printStackTrace();
        }
        return savetext;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource().equals(mobile))
        {
            MobileHome openB = new MobileHome();
            this.dispose();
        }
        if(e.getSource().equals(browser))
        {
            BrowserHome openB = new BrowserHome();
            this.dispose();
        }
    }

    public SplashScreen()
    {
        super("Trust Wizard");

        JTextArea homeText = new JTextArea(25, 30);
        homeText.setText(read());

        JScrollPane homeScroll = new JScrollPane(homeText);

        welc = new JLabel("Welcome To The Trust Wizard");
        home = new JPanel();
        mobile = new JButton("Mobile Wizard");
        browser = new JButton("Browser Wizard");

        home.add(welc);
        home.add(homeScroll);
        home.add(mobile);
        home.add(browser);

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("hand.jpg");
        setIconImage(img.getImage());

        mobile.addActionListener(this);
        browser.addActionListener(this);

        getContentPane().add(home);
        home.repaint();
        setSize(450, 530);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SplashScreen test = new SplashScreen();

    }
}
```

Comment: after reading each line you have to append that line by `\n` newline escape sequence.

Comment: I'd be concerned that the scroll panes preferred size is actually 0x0 (or close enough to), so it's not showing up. Try giving the text area a column and row value to encourage it to have a larger size

Comment: `BufferedReader.readLine()` corrupts your data by eating newlines. You have to add them back yourself, but then you can never know if you're adding back the correct newline or if the last line had a newline at the end. Or better yet, don't use that method. There is no reason you have to read the data by line. Just use one of the other `read()` methods.

Answer (score 5):

Don't write your own method to load data into a JTextArea.

```
//homeText.setText(read());
```

Instead, just use the read() method provided by the JTextArea API:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader( your file name here );
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
homeText.read( br, null );
br.close();
```

Comment: Never ever use `FileReader`. It makes it impossible to specify the encoding to use, and therefore it corrupts your data if the default encoding of the platform it's run on doesn't match the encoding of the file.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström maybe could be there caused by another issue (user on Win, full localized, cp1250/ISO 8859-2 and similair non ASCII charsets)

Comment: @mKorbel: I don't understand you, please elaborate. No matter which other encoding related problems you may have, `FileReader` will definitely corrupt your data sooner or later.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström no idea whats happened, could be your question with runnable code and (to question copy - paste for potential answerers) sticked text caused a.m. corruption

Comment: @mKorbel: I'm not saying any of the data here on StackOverflow was corrupted. I'm saying that if you use `FileReader` in your software, the non-ASCII data read into that software via `FileReader` will be corrupted, depending on which platform you run it on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending just `text`, try appending `text + "\n"`

```
public String read() {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
        String text = null;
        while((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(text + "\n");
        }
    } catch(IOException jim) {
        jim.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null) reader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Also added a `finally` block to close the `BufferedReader` (and with it the rest of the stream)

Comment: Never ever use `FileReader`. It makes it impossible to specify the encoding to use, and therefore it corrupts your data if the default encoding of the platform it's run on doesn't match the encoding of the file.

Comment: What do you suggest instead of FileReader? InputStreamReader? This helps if you know the file encoding, but if not, you might as well use FileReader.

Comment: @EdwardFalk: You need to always know the encoding! If you don't, your data will be corrupted. Worse, if you use `FileReader`, your data will be unpredictably corrupted. The [Javadoc for `FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) tells you what to do instead: "To specify these values yourself, construct an `InputStreamReader` on a `FileInputStream`.".

Answer (score 0):

`homeText.setLineWrap(true);` should do the trick for you.

Put that line right after the where you create the `homeText` variable and then your text will wrap to the size of your `JTextArea`.

Also put a `StringBuilder` in your `while` loop instead of using String concatenation which has a lot of overhead.