# How to display contents of file in GUI in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jlist

I am reading  a file and then display its contents on GUI.

```
FileReader reader = null;
try {
  reader = new FileReader("Catalog.txt");
  catTextField.read(reader, "catTextield");

} 

catch (IOException exception) {
  exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

My Catalog.txt is:

Vehicle ID: 45, Company: Honda, Name: City, Model: 2012, Colors: Black|Silver|White, Available: 3
Vehicle ID: 555, Company: Toyota, Name: Corolla, Model: 2012, Colors: Black|Silver|White, Available: 6

The problem is, the output doesnt display these contents - it is just BLANK.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: have you heard about JTextArea()?? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am very new to the GUI, and finding it hard to relate it to my existing code. I tried JFrame.

Comment: @Prasad i tried JTextArea(), it just shows a blank text area.

Comment: @Basilisk have you set any text to it? Whatever is the output, you can set it to **JTextArea** using `jTextArea.setText("Your output");`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29)<sup>1</sup> (& forget the loop).

1. The method:

> Initializes from a stream. This creates a model of the type appropriate for the component and initializes the model from the stream. ..

Comment: I got the error "non-static method read(Reader,Object) cannot be referenced from a static context". If I declare JtextComponent and make an object it says it can not be instantiated. What do I do?

Comment: *"PLease check edit"*  Please read links carefully before replying.  That uncompilable code snippet is not an SSCCE of a run-time problem.  If you want to post an SSCCE of a compile time problem, make sure it shows exactly the same compilation errors for us, as it does for you (so again, no code snippets - complete class with imports).

Comment: I have tried to make it an SSCCE. I really hope its not vague now. I have a problem similar to this except that Im getting a completely blank output.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356086/how-to-read-text-file-in-jtextarea-in-java-swing

Comment: Also tried this method since you had commented it was a good approach, but to no avail. :(
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16326613/2925258

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text in GUI);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(500,500);
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
List list = new List();
frame.add(list);
File file = new File("Catalog.txt");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line = "";
System.out.println("Catalog:");
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {  
            list.add(line);

    }
br.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("Error opening file");
}
```

}

Comment: Is that an AWT [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/List.html) you are referring to?  Don't mix Swing with AWT without good reason.  The Swing equivalent is `JList`.

Comment: i think with JList add scrolling property mannualy, but List have autoscroll property.

Comment: I don't understand what you were trying to say there, but in any case, that makes no difference.  **Don't mix them unless needed.**  Recent JREs do allow mixing Swing with AWT, but unless the PLAF is set to the native one, it will look rather odd.  There are also a number of other factors for preferring the Swing component.

Comment: If we use JList, how do I add "line" to the list?

Comment: if you use JList add JScrollPane to scroll over the list.  but List automatically add scroll bar.

Comment: No, I mean when I read the content into String "line", how do I add it  to "list" using JList?

Comment: Vaector<String> v = new Vector<>(); v.add(line); list.setListData(v);

Comment: It just shows a blank frame. I also tried JtextArea and it is giving the same result

Comment: I have added the code, can you please tell me why does it give a blank output?